# change order of nodes in subgroup in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

In the following code:

```
digraph G { 
  splines=true;

  bpx_launch -> bpx_preproc [color=red];

  subgraph cluster_0 {
    slice01;
    slice02;
    slice03;
    slice_i;
    slice_N;
    color=black;
  }

  bpx_launch -> bpx_postproc [color=red];
  bpx_launch -> bpx_validate [color=red];
  bpx_launch -> slice01 [color=red];
  bpx_launch -> slice02 [color=red];
  bpx_launch -> slice03 [color=red];
  bpx_launch -> slice_i [color=red];
  bpx_launch -> slice_N [color=red];

  bpx_preproc -> slice01 [color=blue];
  bpx_preproc -> slice02 [color=blue];
  bpx_preproc -> slice03 [color=blue];
  bpx_preproc -> slice_i [color=blue];
  bpx_preproc -> slice_N [color=blue];

  slice01 -> bpx_postproc [color=blue];
  slice02 -> bpx_postproc [color=blue];
  slice03 -> bpx_postproc [color=blue];
  slice_i -> bpx_postproc [color=blue];
  slice_N -> bpx_postproc [color=blue];

  bpx_postproc -> bpx_validate [color=blue];
}
```

I end up getting `slice_N, slice01, slice02, slice03, slice_i`, but I would prefer `slice01, slice02, slice03, slice_i, slice_N`. Is there any way to change that order?

Also, how do I add a key for arrows? I would like to show a little legend which explains that "x -> y" means "x launches y" for red and "x must run before y" for blue.

EDIT: Mistakenly had the first 'bpx_launch' as 'bpx' so it didn't make sense - it should all read as 'bpx_launch' - there should be no node named 'bpx'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (version 2.38) ordering other than by rankdir is not working within clusters neither by the order of appearence nor by edges.

without clusters

```
digraph G { 
    splines=true;

    legend [shape=plaintext label=<<table  border="0" cellborder="0"><tr><td><font color="red">- launches</font></td></tr><tr><td><font color="blue">- runs before</font></td></tr></table>> ]

    { rank=same color=black
        slice01 -> slice02 -> slice03 -> slice_i -> slice_N [style=invis]
    }

    edge [color=red]
    bpx_launch -> bpx_preproc;
    bpx_launch -> bpx_postproc;
    bpx_launch -> bpx_validate;
    bpx_launch -> slice01;
    bpx_launch -> slice02;
    bpx_launch -> slice03;
    bpx_launch -> slice_i;
    bpx_launch -> slice_N;

    edge [color=blue]
    bpx_preproc -> slice01;
    bpx_preproc -> slice02;
    bpx_preproc -> slice03;
    bpx_preproc -> slice_i;
    bpx_preproc -> slice_N;
    slice01 -> bpx_postproc;
    slice02 -> bpx_postproc;
    slice03 -> bpx_postproc;
    slice_i -> bpx_postproc;
    slice_N -> bpx_postproc;
    bpx_postproc -> bpx_validate;
}
```

you get

[image]

Comment: Is there a bug report filed for this issue (that "Currently (version 2.38) ordering other than by rankdir is not working within clusters neither by the order of appearence nor by edges")? Are there discussions of it somewhere? I have been fighting this issue for several days, and would like more information if anyone has it.